# Spring validation for list of accepted string values

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

Is there a **validation annotation** for **Spring** that will do something like:

```
@ValidString({"US", "GB", "CA"})
final String country;
```

and validate that the string is one of the supported values in the array?

Comment: Java has enum types, use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String validation using enum values and annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922655/javax-validation-to-validate-list-of-values

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to create a custom annotation to do this, I would say have an annotation which accepts enum over string comparison, and use it something like this.

```
public enum CountryCode {
   US,
   GB,
   CA;
}

@ValidateString(CountryCode.STRING) 
String code;
```

You may go thru all the responses in this question
[Java String validation using enum values and annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation)

A not so clean way is to use @Pattern annotation with all the country codes in regex.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^(AF|AX|AL|DZ|AS|AD|AO|AI|AQ|AG|AR|AM|AW|AU|AT|AZ|BS|BH|BD|BB|BY|BE|BZ|BJ|BM|BT|BO|BQ|BA|BW|BV|BR|IO|BN|BG|BF|BI|KH|CM|CA|CV|KY|CF|TD|CL|CN|CX|CC|CO|KM|CG|CD|CK|CR|CI|HR|CU|CW|CY|CZ|DK|DJ|DM|DO|EC|EG|SV|GQ|ER|EE|ET|FK|FO|FJ|FI|FR|GF|PF|TF|GA|GM|GE|DE|GH|GI|GR|GL|GD|GP|GU|GT|GG|GN|GW|GY|HT|HM|VA|HN|HK|HU|IS|IN|ID|IR|IQ|IE|IM|IL|IT|JM|JP|JE|JO|KZ|KE|KI|KP|KR|KW|KG|LA|LV|LB|LS|LR|LY|LI|LT|LU|MO|MK|MG|MW|MY|MV|ML|MT|MH|MQ|MR|MU|YT|MX|FM|MD|MC|MN|ME|MS|MA|MZ|MM|NA|NR|NP|NL|NC|NZ|NI|NE|NG|NU|NF|MP|NO|OM|PK|PW|PS|PA|PG|PY|PE|PH|PN|PL|PT|PR|QA|RE|RO|RU|RW|BL|SH|KN|LC|MF|PM|VC|WS|SM|ST|SA|SN|RS|SC|SL|SG|SX|SK|SI|SB|SO|ZA|GS|SS|ES|LK|SD|SR|SJ|SZ|SE|CH|SY|TW|TJ|TZ|TH|TL|TG|TK|TO|TT|TN|TR|TM|TC|TV|UG|UA|AE|GB|US|UM|UY|UZ|VU|VE|VN|VG|VI|WF|EH|YE|ZM|ZW)$",message="invalid code")
private String countryCode;
```